# Extend question with different tag

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, edits

I have a question on StackOverflow [Write decoded from base64 string to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402679/write-decoded-from-base64-string-to-file) where example is a snippet of Python code. Would it be a good idea to add a snippet of Ruby code and add tag 'Ruby'? Or should I create new question? I just wonder if it will not lead to disorder when some person wants to see question related to Ruby but gets example both in Ruby and Python.

Comment: You need the same but now for Ruby, is that the case? And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127992/ruby-1-9-base64-encoding-write-to-file-error) doesn't answer your question in Ruby?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of the script is exactly the same.

Comment: In general a new question would be appropiate so to answer your question: I would not add the ruby-tag. I can't imagine that the specific question you want to as is not already answered. My search indicate that already, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To be honest, I didn't manage to find the answer you have provided above. So, first of all I should try this Ruby example.

Comment: Really? I searched for [`http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+write+base64`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+write+base64), the second result is the one I picked...

Comment: My fault. I need to use search more carefully. About StackOverflow question, it works the same wrong way. No idea how it can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a [questions and answers site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) about programming. It isn't a discussion forum: we want answers that match the question, not extended discussion related to a topic.

If someone is writing a Python program and wants to decode a base64-encoded string, an answer that explains how to do it in Ruby is completely useless, and vice versa. Therefore a question asking how to decode base64 in Python and a question asking how to decode base64 in Ruby are completely different questions.

It's fairly rare that a question should have multiple programming language tags. Usually, it's for interoperability questions (e.g. how to link a library in X with a library in Y).

So ask a new question (or rather, search — given that both base64 and Ruby are fairly popular, it is highly likely that the question has been asked before).